# how to develop a guard slider control for android

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm not sure what's the control name, but I need something like this (see image):

[image]

and I have no idea about how to develop it. On emulator (I got this throw hierarchical view perspective) is called SlidingTab.

Any idea how to start building it? There is something already built I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SlidingTab didn't make it in to the public View api's so you have to grab yourself a copy of the SlidingTab.java file from the project source code. And include it in with your application.

[Here is one copy of it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.java)

Implementing it is fairly straightforward once you get it in to your project. [Here is a javadoc](http://hi-android.info/doc/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.html)

Edit everything came from the SDK inside the folder for whichever platform you want. data/res/ you can find all of the system drawables. I got the mdpi and hdpi ones out of there a while back, here is a zip with those ones to get you started.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5724095/Android%20Apps/SlidingTagRes.zip

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I got the code. Now I have some missing constants in that code, like:

     R.style.TextAppearance_SlidingTabNormal
     R.style.TextAppearance_SlidingTabActive
    
    and 
    
     R.drawable.jog_tab_left_generic
     R.drawable.jog_tab_bar_left_generic
     R.drawable.jog_tab_target_gray
     R.drawable.jog_tab_right_generic
     R.drawable.jog_tab_bar_right_generic
     R.drawable.jog_tab_target_gray

and i'm sure I need some graphics (images used by the control).
How do I get that resources? There is sny way to get a zip file with all the sources?

Comment: You can find the in the data/res folder of a specific platform version in the SDK. see my edit though, I've got them pulled out already and I can throw up a zip file link.

Comment: did you able build this kind of slider ?

Answer (score 0):

That is the Standard Android Lockscreen.
Check out the AOSP Source Code from Git and look for the Class LockScreen.java.